React Fragment Error after upgrading to Nextjs 15
After upgrading project to NextJs 15 I keep getting this error
Invalid prop `id` supplied to `React.Fragment`. React.Fragment can only have `key` and `children` props.

I can see in the console message that its coming from "SlotClone" and "Slot" components, which come from ShadcnUi / Radix primitives. Since I cant change the code in packages, what can I do get rid of those errors?
Just roll back to NextJs 14?


You have any luck on this?

@Leafyshark I rolled back to Nextjs 14. Gonna wait until these new version "kinks" get ironed out. EDIT: Would be useful to check out if this issue has been raised to Nextjs Github discussion so they are aware. I'd imagine by this time they are, but still.
